# Get Garbage When Filling a String From File in C

Tags: c

I am supposed to fill an array of structure from a text file. Here's the definition of the structure:

```
typedef struct{
char name[20];
int age;
}person;
```

This structure is supposed to group data of a user (age and name), which I should get from a file of the following format:
User One 35## Heading ##
User Two 36## Heading ##
User Three 8## Heading ##
Here's a part of the code I proposed (The filling function, called later by the main):

```
void fill_array_elements(person* l_p,int N){

int i,j,index,length;
char temp,First_Name[10],Last_Name[10];
FILE*infp;
infp=fopen("PeopleInfo.txt","r");
if(infp==NULL)
   printf("Could not open file.\n");
else
{
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
 {
    fscanf(infp,"%s",First_Name);
    fscanf(infp,"%s",Last_Name);
    temp=getc(infp);
    fscanf(infp,"%d",&l_p[i].age);
    strcpy(l_p[i].name,First_Name);
    l_p[i].name[strlen(l_p[i].name)]=' ';
    strcat(l_p[i].name,Last_Name);
        }
    }
     fclose(infp);
    }
```

When I try displaying my array, I always get garbage in the first string of the following formqt: User %:n5jnfOne. The other strings are printed normally. Is it a simple concidence or my code is all wrong? (I tried with several first lines, always get the same output)
Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
l_p[i].name[strlen(l_p[i].name)]=' ';
```

replaces the \0 terminator with a space. It does not add a new terminator, so there is no terminator and whatever happens to come after the string is considered to be part of the string.

The simplest solution is to use `strcat` like usual, even though you're only appending one character:

```
strcat(l_p[i].name, " ");
```

Comment: Thank you it's working now! I tried appending using single quotes at the beginning. I did not know I could append one character just like a whole string :D

Comment: @Njw96 `' '` is the space character; `" "` is a string containing one character (which is the space character).